# Export URLs accessed in each session from Google Analytics

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using Google Analytics [Sessions API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessions) I can get the total hits (i.e. total page views and events etc) in a session.

Is there a way to get a list of all the page views and events that took place in a session? If this data cannot be obtained using core reporting API can it be exported to BigTable if Google Analytics Premium is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions.

One common solution and the easiest one is add the user id as a "custom dimension", so in that way you can extract all your data by user (that includes the sessions and interactions).

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-54241350-4', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId'));
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

This works for me, but i need to warn you that this code is on a gray area, because depending the Google Team that is watching your account, you can and can't do this because it can be considered as a policy violation (capacity of isolation of a session).

Or via Google Big Query you can do via

```
SELECT 
    hits.page,
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId, string(VisitId)) AS VId,
    CONCAT(visitId, date) AS SID
FROM  
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-05-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-05-10')) 
GROUP BY 
    hits.page, VId, SID
```

But this solution is only for Premium User, if that is you case you can opt to get a free quota in Big Query.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself, but the [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) lists several relevant fields if you want to export sessions such as fullvisitorId (a.k.a. Clientid), Visitnumber and Visitid ("An identifier for this session"). So I'd say yes, this should be possible using BigQuery (by exporting each hits.page.pagePath per visitid).